# Change actionOverflowButtonStyle with appcompat v21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-appcompat, android-support-design

I want to change the action overflow button icon in my `Toolbar` (or `ActionBar`, not matter).

So I go this way:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.OverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.OverflowButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_custom</item>
</style>
```

or this way:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ToolbarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ToolbarStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.OverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.OverflowButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_custom</item>
</style>
```

But both ways don't work. What's wrong there?

And the second question is can I change one resourse from library to another resource from library (I just want to change black action overflow button to white, which presents in the library too).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can define the overflow icon in the app theme using the **`actionOverflowButtonStyle`** attribute.

With a **Material Components Theme**:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="srcCompat">@drawable/my_overflow_menu</item>
</style>
```

With an **AppCompat Theme**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
   <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_myoverflow</item>
</style>
```

With appcompat you have to use the attributes without the android namaspace.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Do we need to use it twice? 

I mean `<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>` AND `<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>`.

Also is it possible to use resource from library? I cannot find two variants of the overflow button. But library contains black and white, isn't it?

Comment: You can find the icon also in the new icon set http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets.html#sticker-sheets-components. Check the answer if it can be useful for other users.

Comment: I am using my theme with `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` and overriding OverFlow button has no effect :(

Comment: the "without android namespace" did it for me!

Comment: Can you just change the color, not the icon?

Comment: You can change the color by applying a tint:
`<style name="actionOverflowButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="tint">@color/White</item>
    </style>`